# LocationManager GPS_PROVIDER not working on device

Tags: android, gps, location

tell me please how i can get lat and long  from GPS_PROVIDER . 
**my code**

```
TextView curb,cura ;
Button b,a;
LocationManager lm;
boolean apres=false;
boolean bpresss=false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
     l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     cura = new TextView (this);
     a = new Button(this);
     a.setText("GPS get lat and long");

     lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bpresss=false;
            apres =true;

             lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, MainActivity.this); 
        }
    });

     b = new Button(this);
     curb = new TextView(this);
     b.setText("NETWORK get lat long");
     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            apres=false;
            bpresss =true;
            Log.e("","NETWORK BUTTON PRESSED");

             lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, MainActivity.this); 
            Log.e("","NETWORK BUTTON UNPRESSED");
        }
    });
     setContentView(l);
     l.addView(cura);
     l.addView(a);
     l.addView(curb);
     l.addView(b);

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(apres){
        cura.setText("lat = "+loc.getLatitude()+"   long = "+loc.getLongitude());
        apres=false;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(bpresss){
        Log.e("","---------------");
        curb.setText("lat = "+loc.getLatitude()+"   long = "+loc.getLongitude());
        bpresss=false;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NETWORK Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Problem:** App work ... strange on emulator and than work very strang on real device.
On emulator i can easly get  GPS coords, but NETWORK not working. Just not pressing .

On real device  GPS coords not working ,but netwrok working very well.
I want to know how to properly get GPS Coords for currelnt location on real device. ?

Just when press button on real device - then nothing. No coords. Emulator from genymotion work very well with gps.

Answer (score 0):

gps sometimes takes more than 1 minute to lock and give you appropriate location so you can't guarantee that on button click the gps will be locked and you will get a location.what you can do is wait for some time and try to get the location after confirming that gps has been locked

Comment: and no way to catch when i can use gps location ?

Comment: there is no definite timeframe sometimes it get locked in less than 10 seconds and provide location other times it takes 1-3 minutes to provide a location what you can do is wait for a duration like 20-30 seconds to provide a location and if in that duration gps do not provide a location you can pick up the location through the network